# What are the recommended sources for research about conceptual metaphor?

Tags: semantics, resource-request, pragmatics, datasets

I would like to find what have been done in research about conceptual metaphor. I've looked into some database, e.g. ERIC, Sciencedirect, WileyOnlineLibrary, JSTOR, Cambridgecore, Taylor&Francis, etc. But I can find just a few research about conceptual metaphor. Does anyone have other resources or tips for searching?

Answer (score 1):

Try George Lakoff and Mark Johnson's *Metaphors we live by* as a starter. This tiny book is widely available in libraries. It's going to give you an idea what to look for later. Additionally, there is a bibliography there as well.

Comment: Yes, that's a good place to start. Here's my [review of the book](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/L&J-Lg-Review.pdf), from _Language_.

Comment: Yes. I've read that.